# Dropdown list , inside dropdownlist. Subdir overflow hidden not working

Tags: html, css, dropdown

It's late and I'm breaking my head on this. I'm building a page which shows content of the local machine. I'm having a structure exactly the same as in Pedro Nauck's pen on codepen. (http://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/jaluz)

In my third, and last, list item I build a deeper structure with another list per list-item, I'm trying to add a subdirectory-structure here. Everything is working fine, exept for: The sub-directory structure isn't expanding, it stay's the same height as the list item itself and becomes scrollable.

In my code below, you may find some weird things, that's because I've experimented a lot ! :)

PS: The page with full content was to big to show, but I tried the code below in a simple index.html and it show's exactly what I mean, you get a header and when you click it, the directory rolls out, which have exactly the same styling as the header. (confusing, I know.) But when you click the directory it becomes scrollable and you can scroll through the subdirectorie's. I don't want it scrollable (overflow: hidden) but want it to expand, just like the directorie's.

I'm off to bed now ! Hoping for some insight's ...

Code:

```
<head>   <title>Local</title>   <style>
    .sites-dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }

    .sites-dropdown a {
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #C8C8C8;
      font-size: 0.75em;
      letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    }

    .sites-dropdown [data-toggle="sites-dropdown"] {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      background: #646464;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 25px;
    }

    .sites-dropdown [data-toggle="sites-dropdown"]:hover {
      background: #646464;
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .sites-dropdown [data-toggle="sites-dropdown"]:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '\25BC';
      font-size: 0.7em;
      color: #fff;
      top: 13px;
      right: 10px;
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
    }

    .sites-dropdown > .dropdown-sites {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
      transform: scaleY(0);
      -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
    }

    .sites-dropdown > .dropdown-sites li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    .sites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"] {
      opacity: 0;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .sites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown-sites {
      max-height: 9999px;
      display: block;
      -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
      transform: scaleY(1);
      animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .sites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a[data-toggle="sites-dropdown"]:before {
      -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
    }

    li {
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.8rem;
      font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #444;
    }

    .sites-item {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .arrow {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      width: 3%;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .sites {
      text-align: left;
    }

    .sitename {
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 42%; // initially, width:42%
    }

    .sitelmd {
      font-size: 0.6rem;
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 23%; // initially, width:23%
    }

    .sitesize {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: left;
      min-width: 16%; // initially, width:16%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .siteadmin {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: right;
      min-width: 5%; // initially, width:5%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .siteadmin:hover {
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .sites li {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2rem;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 2s ease;
      transition: background 2s ease;
    }

    .sites li:nth-child(even) {
      background: #fff;
    }

    .sites li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #fff;
    }

    .sites li:nth-child(even):hover {
      -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      transition: background 0.2s ease;
      background: #06ffb5;
      /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* Standard syntax */
    }

    .sites li:nth-child(odd):hover {
      -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      transition: background 0.2s ease;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* Standard syntax */
    }

    .sites li:hover .no-img2 {
      background-color: #2dc878;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
      -o-transition: all .2s ease;
      transition: all .2s ease;
    }

    .sites li:hover .arrow {
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .filename {
      width: 33%;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .datelastmodified {
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 33%; // initially, width:33%
      text-align: center;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .filesize {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      width: 33%;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .icon2,
    .sites img {
      float: top;
      font-size: .7rem;
      display: inline-block;
      text-indent: -10000px;
      background-size: 1.2rem;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      display: none;
    }

    .sites img,
    .sites .no-img2 {
      float: left;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
      -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
      -o-transition: all 2s ease;
      transition: all 2s ease;
    }

    .sites .no-img2 {
      background-color: #999;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown a {
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 25px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #C8C8C8;
      font-size: 0.75em;
      letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown [data-toggle="subsites-dropdown"] {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      background: #646464;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 25px;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown [data-toggle="subsites-dropdown"]:hover {
      background: #646464;
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown [data-toggle="subsites-dropdown"]:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '\25BC';
      font-size: 0.7em;
      color: #fff;
      top: 13px;
      right: 10px;
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown > .dropdown-subsites {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
      transform: scaleY(0);
      -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
      animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown > .dropdown-subsites li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"] {
      opacity: 0;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown-subsites {
      max-height: 9999px;
      display: block;
      -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
      transform: scaleY(1);
      animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
      transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .subsites-dropdown > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a[data-toggle="subsites-dropdown"]:before {
      -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
    }

    li {
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.8rem;
      font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #444;
    }

    .subsites-item {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .arrow {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      width: 3%;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .subsites {
      text-align: left;
    }

    .sitename {
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 42%; // initially, width:42%
    }

    .sitelmd {
      font-size: 0.6rem;
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 23%; // initially, width:23%
    }

    .subsitesize {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: left;
      min-width: 16%; // initially, width:16%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .siteadmin {
      color: #C8C8C8;
      float: right;
      min-width: 5%; // initially, width:5%;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .siteadmin:hover {
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .subsites li {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2rem;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: background 2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 2s ease;
      transition: background 2s ease;
    }

    .subsites li:nth-child(even) {
      background: #fff;
    }

    .subsites li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #fff;
    }

    .subsites li:nth-child(even):hover {
      -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      transition: background 0.2s ease;
      background: #06ffb5;
      /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1));
      /* Standard syntax */
    }

    .subsites li:nth-child(odd):hover {
      -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
      transition: background 0.2s ease;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 255, 181, 0.1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1));
      /* Standard syntax */
    }

    .subsites li:hover .no-img2 {
      background-color: #2dc878;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
      -o-transition: all .2s ease;
      transition: all .2s ease;
    }

    .subsites li:hover .arrow {
      color: #06ffb5;
    }

    .filename {
      width: 33%;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .datelastmodified {
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 33%; // initially, width:33%
      text-align: center;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .filesize {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      width: 33%;
      color: #C8C8C8;
    }

    .icon2,
    .subsites img {
      float: top;
      font-size: .7rem;
      display: inline-block;
      text-indent: -10000px;
      background-size: 1.2rem;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      display: none;
    }

    .subsites img,
    .subsites .no-img2 {
      float: left;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
      -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
      -o-transition: all 2s ease;
      transition: all 2s ease;
    }

    .sites .no-img2 {
      background-color: #999;
    }   </style> </head>

<body id="grad"> </body> <ul>   <li class="sites-dropdown">
    <!-- Compared to the last item of this list, the structure is about the same, although it has one <ul> less.  -->   </li>   <li class="sites-dropdown">
    <!-- Compared to the last item of this list, the structure is about the same, although it has one <ul> less.  -->   </li>   <li class="sites-dropdown">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <a href="#" class="sites-header-top" data-toggle="sites-dropdown">
      <span class="filename">Templates</span>
      <span class="datelastmodified">Last modified</span>
      <span class="filesize">Size</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-sites sites">
      <li class="subsites-dropdown subdir-sites-dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a href="#" class="subsites-header-top" data-toggle="subsites-dropdown">
          <span class="filename">animation</span>
          <span class="datelastmodified">Last modified</span>
          <span class="filesize">Size</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-subsites subsites">
          <!-- This <ul> is styled exactly the same as as the others, exept for experimenting I changend all the "sites"-classes to "subsites"-classes, without any succes for now. -->
          <li class="subsites-item">
            <a class="subfolder subsite" href="http://animation-1.template" target="_blank">
              <span class="arrow">▶ </span>
              <span class="sitename">animation-1</span>
            </a>
            <span class="sitelmd">Sun, 13 Dec 2015 12:05:55 +0100</span>
            <span class="sitesize">30.6 Mb</span>
          </li>
          <li class="subsites-item">
            <a class="subfolder subsite" href="http://animation-2.template" target="_blank">
              <span class="arrow">▶ </span>
              <span class="sitename">animation-2</span>
            </a>
            <span class="sitelmd">Sun, 13 Dec 2015 12:08:16 +0100</span>
            <span class="sitesize">34 Mb</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>   </li> </ul> </body>
```